# PHP switch and translations

Tags: coding-standards

Given a PHP switch statement, would it be a good (or bad) idea to use `t()` in `case` statements?

```
switch ($button_value) {
  case t('Clear'):
    // …
    break;
  case t('Search'):
    // …
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 7 uses code similar to the following one. (See [`image_style_form_submit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.admin.inc/function/image_style_form_submit/7.x).)

```
  if ($form_state['values']['op'] == t('Update style')) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Changes to the style have been saved.'));
  }
```

That code is necessary to handle the submission done from two different buttons with the same form submission handler. (See [`image_style_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.admin.inc/function/image_style_form/7.x); comments starting with *kll* are mine.)

```
  // kll: This is the first button using that submission handler.
  $form['effects']['new']['add'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add'),
    '#validate' => array('image_style_form_add_validate'),
    '#submit' => array('image_style_form_submit', 'image_style_form_add_submit'),
  );

  // Show the Override or Submit button for this style.
  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['override'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Override defaults'),
    '#validate' => array(),
    '#submit' => array('image_style_form_override_submit'),
    '#access' => !$editable,
  );

  // kll: This is the second button using that submission handler.
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Update style'),
    '#access' => $editable,
  );
```

Avoiding to check the value of `$form_state['values']['op']` can be easily accomplished by using different submission handlers for different buttons.

I think this is the only case Drupal 7 uses the value returned from `t()` in a control structure; it can be avoided, and Drupal 8 does avoid that.

Generally speaking, using a string that is shown in the user interface in a control structure should be avoided, since any change to the text presented to the user would require a change in the logic of a different function. Since `t()` is used with strings shown to the users, code like the one you shown should be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it would be a bad development practice. The whole purpose of [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7.x) is to provide *human-readable translated text*. As such, it can't be guaranteed as consistent switch logic because the translation context might differ.

In practice (e.g. a input button submit value on a basic form with little-to-no translation contexts), you might get away with it, but you're adding technical debt; if your application grows and other features start to rely on the switch logic, it's only a matter of time before the inconsistent logic will bite you.